# Como mover um arquivo para outra pasta no Sublime text?

Tags: sublime-text

Como mover um arquivo para outra pasta no **Sublime text**?

Se eu tenho essa estrutura

```
-- storage/
---- src/
-- /index.php
```

Como poderia mover `index.php` para `src/storage/index.php`?

```
-- storage/
---- src/
------ index.php
```

**Observação**: Essa pergunta vale para o Sublime Text `2` ou `3`, já que nunca soube como mover arquivos em nenhum deles.

Comment: Talvez com algum plugin, ou através do console, mas através da UI não é possível.

Comment: Tem apenas um jeito que eu sei, mas é meio chato de fazer

Comment: Se possível, compartilhe, pois eu mesmo sempre utilizei um console externo, e seria ótimo fazer isso dentro do sublime =]

Comment: Você clica com o direito sobre o arquivo, clica em "rename", e em seguida renomeia o arquivo apontando para o diretório que quer mover. Exemplo: `index.php` => `src/storage/index.php`, ou `../storage/index.php`

Comment: Que da hora! Obrigado por ter compartilhado! E desculpe não poder ajudar mais...

Comment: Sugiro que instale o [sidebar enhancements](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarEnhancements), é sensacional!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ninguém respondeu ainda :(

Mas aqui vou deixar minha pequena solução para esse problema no Sublime Text.

## Movendo um arquivo no `Sublime Text`.

- Clique no arquivo que deseja mover com o botão direito;
- Selecione "rename";
- Em seguida renomei o arquivo apontando para o diretório que quer movê-lo.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há ainda alguns truques como, por exemplo, você mover para uma pasta que está a um nível acima usando `../usuarios/nome_do_arquivo`.